# What material to put between in-corner closet and walls

Tags: closet

I have a wardrobe closet in the corner of my bedroom with a half inch space on the left, rear and top sides (almost reaches ceiling too).

Does it make sense to put a kind of dense foam in these spaces to make it look "built in" and in addition, prevent dust from gathering.

What kind of material is recommended?

Comment: picture would help

Comment: Yes, pictures, please. But what you probably want is either to move the closet inward and close the gap (possibly involves baseboard removal), or what cabinet people call "scribe strip" to bridge the gap.